# iPhone TableView: defining padding between images and text in a cell

Tags: iphone, alignment, padding, tableview

does anybody know how to vertically align these text elements. I would like to define an absolute left padding for the text which is not affected by each image dimensions.  It's quite annoying like this:

[image]

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1) `UITableViewCell` has a `textLabel` property which you can access and adjust the frame. See the Apple [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info on `UITableViewCell`

2) You can ensure that all of your icons have the same width.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by slecifying the frame on your UIImage, UILabel, or both. Set the float x to a safe distance from the left on the label or specify the width of your widest image as the width of the UIImage frame.

I can clarify more if needed when I'm not on my mobile.